# z-index position absolute vs fixed

Tags: css, css-position

I have a tabular view whose thead is fixed and web's header and filter section is also fixed, so filter section contains a bootstrap dropdown whose z-index is 1000 & thead's z-index is 1 but still that dropdown is going behind it, below is the screenshot:

[image]

Here sortby (`position: absolute; z-index:1000`) is going behind that fixed header (`position: fixed; z-index:1`)

Edit: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s86dadmw/)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: or provide the site url (if it's not backend)

Comment: that happened to me a few days ago, I don't know if it's a good idea, but try to set z-index: -1 to the fixed header. It should work.

Comment: @Ivan if I set it to z-index then tbody will overlap thead

Comment: Added fiddle please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thead `z-index:1` and `drop-down z-index:9;` works, try and adjust it's top and margin values too.

```
.inline-edit > thead {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    top: 150px;
}
.inline-edit thead > tr {
    display: block;
}
.inline-edit thead > tr > th {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.inline-edit > tbody {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 78px;
}

.top_filter {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 54px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent div z-index take affect. you must give the `container-fluid` a higher `z-index` like the `table-responsive`

check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/uwdncha0/1/